# What's the purpose of Eclipse tags - like @author, @version, @link?

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, tags

I've noticed that Eclipse automatically adds an `@author` tag with my name at the top of a new Java class.  I also noticed that there are other tags available like `@version`, `@link`, `@code`, `@value`, `@see`...

Is it just another 'convention' that has formed so that code remains well-documented?  Or is there some other purpose?

I tried finding a website that would give better descriptions of the tags and their usage, but I didn't have any luck.

Comment: These are javadoc tags. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#javadoctags

Comment: Thanks for that link.  That really helps.

Comment: @evan: I think you can elaborate a little on that, and then post it as an answer.

Comment: Link above is dead. [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tagcomments) may be today's equivalent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are Javadoc tags related to the Javadoc mechanism. When you'll generate the Javadoc (there's an option in the Eclipse menu for that), those link will be interpreted appropriately and the Javadoc will be better detailed. See the link in the comment for the list of all available tags.

Underestimate the power of documentation you will not.

Comment: These aren't annotations, but they are javadoc tags.

Comment: Thanks I just looked it up in the Java doc and you're right, `Annotations complement javadoc tags`. I'm changing it right now.